# Displaying photo from photopath in eval repeater ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display images in eval repeater but it doesn't work. When I put simply div instead of asp:Repeater I get the image path. (I have no problem with SQL side)

Can anyone tell what's wrong with this code?

Thanks.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="<%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %>" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>




SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=whitehouse;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PresidentPhotoPath FROM presidents", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Repeater1.DataSource = dr;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        cnn.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What does a sample path look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ImageUrl` syntax here is wrong:

```
ImageUrl="<%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %> "
```

You have double quotes inside of double quotes, change the outer quotes to be single quotes, like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %>'
```

---

As for your issue with prepending `Images/` before the file name, I would recommend using a code-behind method to build the string for you, like this:

```
protected string BuildPath(string photoPath)
{
    return "Images/ + photoPath;
}
```

> Note: Consider naming this something more useful than `BuildPath` as that is fairly generic, just picked that name because nothing better came to mind immediately.

Now in your markup you can just call the method, like this:

```
ImageUrl='<%# BuildPath(Eval("PresidentPhotoPath")) %>'
```

I recommend this approach for the following reasons:

- The markup does not contain any complex logic whatsoever, just a method call with the `Eval()` value
- It is easier to debug the logic versus embedded code blocks
- You can leverage the power of Visual Studio compiler to catch syntax errors at compile-time versus run-time errors when the logic is embedded into the binding syntax of the markup

Comment: make it ```ImageUrl='/Images<%# Eval("PresidentPhotoPath") %>'```

Comment: @thenewseattle - updated answer to use code-behind to build the string, which is much easier to work with than the embedded code blocks in the markup.